# Glassfish 4 (Spring MVC/JSP/Hibernate Application) builds up HEAP

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, out-of-memory, glassfish-4

Our Glassfish 4 Application Server builds up heap space and hangs while testing high loads (200 parallel connections). We used different garbage collection settings while testing.

The application runs on a clustered Glassfish Server with one Administration Domain and two instances using --availabilityenabled=true to share session data. But we can reproduce the Heap building up on non clustered Glassfish Servers (running on our desktops), too.

We are using the following Spring/Hibernate Versions:

- spring 4.0.1 (including webmvc, aop, context, beans, binding, jdbc, web, tx)
- spring-security 3.2.0
- hibernate 4.3.1 (core, entitymanager, validator)
- jsp 2.2
- elasticsearch 1.0.0

### Stiuation

While normal testing the Heap starts to load up. Garbage collection is trying to do its job but the used Heap still rises.

(Whish I could post images...) you would see a rise of approx. 300M in 20 hours.

When using JMeter to simulate higher load the Heap Usage starts to rise. After 2 hours of 200 simultanious connections the Heap rises to 6G (from 0.5G) and it continues to rise till 8G is reached (approx. 4 hours in). Then bad things happen.

When performing test for 2 hours only (reaching 6G of Heap) the heap does not shrink, even when performing manual GC or leaving the Glassfish without new connections for 24 hours. It stays at 6G.

### Heap dump

I took a Heapdump after 2 hours of testing:

```
class                                                              instances
java.util.ArrayList                                                19.904.237
java.lang.Object[]                                                 15.851.496
org.jboss.weld.util.collections.ArraySet                            9.192.068
org.jboss.weld.bean.interceptor.WeldInterceptorClassMetadata        9.188.347
java.util.HashMap$Entry                                             5.546.603
java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccesList                   5.331.810
java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccesList                   5.328.892
java.lang.reflect.Constructor                                       2.669.192
com.google.common.collect.MapMakerInternalMap$StrongEntity          2.667.181
com.google.common.collect.MapMakerInternalMap$StrongValueReference  2.667.181
org.jboss.weld.injection.AbstractCallableInjectionPoint$1           2.664.747
org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint                  2.664.737
org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget               2.664.737
org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInstanciator               2.664.731
```

### Current Configuration

```
Java:   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, 1.7.0_51-b13
JVM:    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 24.51-b03, mixed mode
Server: Server GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

Our current settings are:

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:NewRatio=4
-Xms4096m
-Xss256k
-Xmx8G
-javaagent:/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
[...]
```

### Server Hardware

One server has 14 (including hyperthreading) CPU Cores, 32GB of ram and runs Glassfish and ElasticSearch. The Load never reaches 5 till Heap is nearly full and excessive garbage collecting kicks in. Load then rises massively.

What are we doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weld, which is the implementation of CDI in Glassfish has a known memory leak in the version that ships with Glassfish 4.  See:  https://community.jboss.org/message/848709.  You can replace the weld jar file to upgrade to version 2.0.5.Final.  This will sorta fix the situation in that you will no longer see "org.jboss.weld.bean.interceptor.WeldInterceptorClassMetadata" classes grow without bound in your heap dumps.

There is another memory leak due to using tag files with parameters with CDI enabled (which is generally the case since GlassFish 4 will eagerly enable CDI by default even if you don't use it or have a beans.xml).  As a workaround disable CDI or use a jsp segment include instead of a tag.  See https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-4-memory-leak